# How to hide a route from API Platform documentation

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm building an API with API Platform under Symfony4,

I want to hide an entity in the doc which is accessible only to the ROLE_ADMIN of the blow no interest to be visible in the doc.

Here is the entity I want to hide:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={"access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OrderStatusRepository")
 */
class OrderStatus
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups("orderGET")
     */
    private $label;

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getLabel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->label;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $label
     * @return OrderStatus
     */
    public function setLabel(string $label): self
    {
        $this->label = $label;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 11):

Symfony allows to decorate services, here we need to decorate `api_platform.openapi.factory`

Create `src/OpenApi/OpenApiFactory.php` with the following:

```php
<?php

namespace App\OpenApi;

use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\Factory\OpenApiFactoryInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\Model\PathItem;
use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\OpenApi;

class OpenApiFactory implements OpenApiFactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var OpenApiFactoryInterface
     */
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(OpenApiFactoryInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function __invoke(array $context = []): OpenApi
    {
        $openApi = $this->decorated->__invoke($context);

        /** @var PathItem $path */
        foreach ($openApi->getPaths()->getPaths() as $key => $path) {
            if ($path->getGet() && $path->getGet()->getSummary() === 'hidden') {
                $openApi->getPaths()->addPath($key, $path->withGet(null));
            }
        }

        return $openApi;
    }
}
```

Register it

```yaml
services:
    App\OpenApi\OpenApiFactory:
        decorates: 'api_platform.openapi.factory'
        arguments: ['@App\OpenApi\OpenApiFactory.inner']
        autoconfigure: false
```

Add `openapi_context` to each route you want to hide

```php
 * @ApiResource(
 *   itemOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              ...
 *              "openapi_context"={
 *                  "summary"="hidden"
 *              }
 *          }
 *   }
 * )
```

Answer (score 6):

This isn't supported out of the box (but it would be a nice contribution).
What you can do is to decorate the `DocumentationNormalizer` to `unset()` the paths you don't want to appear in the OpenAPI documentation.

More information about overriding the specification in the [API Platform OpenAPI documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/openapi/#overriding-the-openapi-specification)

Answer (score 2):

As Kevin said you can `unset` paths & definitions you want to hide.

In my case I wanted to do the opposite, whitelisting specific actions.

```yml
# config/services.yaml
    App\Swagger\SwaggerDecorator:
            decorates: 'api_platform.swagger.normalizer.api_gateway'
            arguments: [ '@App\Swagger\SwaggerDecorator.inner' ]
            autoconfigure: false
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Swagger;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

final class SwaggerDecorator implements NormalizerInterface
{
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $allowedPaths = [
            '/users',
            '/users/{id}',
        ];
        $allowedDefinitions = [
            'User',
        ];

        $docs = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);

        $publicPaths = [];
        $publicDefinitions = [];
        foreach ($docs['paths'] as $path => $definition) {
            if (in_array($path, $allowedPaths)) {
                $publicPaths[$path] = $definition;
            }
        }
        foreach ($docs['definitions'] as $class => $definition) {
            if (in_array($class, $allowedDefinitions)) {
                $publicDefinitions[$class] = $definition;
            }
        }

        $docs['paths'] = $publicPaths;
        $docs['definitions'] = $publicDefinitions;

        return $docs;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $this->decorated->supportsNormalization($data, $format);
    }
}
```

Comment: As of API Platform 2.6, `api_platform.swagger.normalizer.api_gateway` became `api_platform.openapi.normalizer.api_gateway`

Comment: $docs['definitions'] no longer exists either, if using 2.6/OpenApi you will need to check within docs['components']['schemas'] instead

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible in API Platform v3.2 (probably since v3). See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74055693/2674501.

Note that it is for **Symfony 6+**, which does not match the OP requirements.

[Disabling an Operation From OpenAPI Documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/openapi/#disabling-an-operation-from-openapi-documentation)

```php
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(openapi: false)
    ]
)]
```