# API Platform: Hide properties in /api/contexts/<entity>

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

When working with the API platform (Symfony) I only expose some of my entity's properties to the API. That works pretty good with groups, the output DTO and DataTransformer. When opening the API under `/api/<entity>` I get the results with only the defined/grouped properties.

However when having a opening the contexts under `/api/contexts/<entity>` ALL properties are listed. How can I reduce those properties as well?

Symfony Version: 6

Api Platform Version: 2.6.8

Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EntityRepository::class)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups" = {"api:read"}},
 *     collectionOperations={"get"},
 *     itemOperations={"get"},
 *     order={"title"="ASC"},
 *     paginationEnabled=false,
 *     output=EntityApiOutput::class
 * )
 */
class Entity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"api:read"}) */
    private $id;
    
    // other properties without '@Groups'
```

EntityApiOutput:

```
class EntityApiOutput
{
    /** @Groups({"api:read"}) */
    public int $id;

    /** @Groups({"api:read"}) */
    public string $title;
}
```

Comment: Does this help by adding the [norm/denorm context attributes](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#using-serialization-groups)..

Comment: @Bossman Unfortuntely not :( I added the entity and the DTO

Comment: A couple of places to take a look on: [This github issue](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/189#issuecomment-264016123)
[Api Platform serialization docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/)
[A good old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54344744/17089665)