# Hide an item operation - API Platform

Tags: api-platform.com

I want to hide/disable an endpoint `/users/{id}`
[image]

I can disable it like thus simply:

```
#[ApiResource(
    shortName: 'Users',
    collectionOperations: ['GET'],
    itemOperations:[],
    normalizationContext: [
        'skip_null_values' => false,
    ],
)]
```

But when I hit my `/users` endpoint I get the following error:-

`No item route associated with the type \"App\\Entity\\User`

So, I read up around this topic and try:-

```
#[ApiResource(
    shortName: 'Users',
    collectionOperations: ['GET'],
    itemOperations: ['GET' => [
        "method" => "GET",
            "controller" => NotFoundAction::class,
            "read" => false,
            "output" => false
    ]],
    normalizationContext: [
        'skip_null_values' => false,
    ],
)]
```

Back at my endpoint `/users` now works but my other route `/users/{id}` has re-appeared again? Anyone struggling with hiding routes with api platform?

**Edit**

doesn't fly whatsoever. My IDE light's this up like:-
[image]

looks like `operations` doesn't exist within the current library?

`$itemOperations` exists in `vendor/api-platform/core/src/Annotation/ApiResource.php` though?

```
new Get(),
new GetCollection()
```

are un-obtainable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deactivate the operation:

[Enabling and Disabling Operations](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#enabling-and-disabling-operations)

> If you do not want to allow access to the resource item (i.e. you don't want a GET item operation), instead of omitting it altogether, you should instead declare a GET item operation which returns HTTP 404 (Not Found), so that the resource item can still be identified by an IRI.

To hide the operation from OpenAPI:

[Disabling an Operation From OpenAPI Documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/openapi/#disabling-an-operation-from-openapi-documentation)

```
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(openapi: false)
    ]
)]
```

It is documented for the API Platform version 3.0.

Additionally (for older API Platform versions) check the following website:

[Decorating the API Platform Documentation Normalizer](https://timobakx.dev/php/api-platform/2021/06/06/altering-api-documentation-generated-by-apip.html)

With the help of the Normalizer you will be able to manipulate every part of the OpenAPI docs output.

Comment: Problem is I'm using version 2.6

Comment: Please check the two links I attached to my post. They are valid for older versions.

Comment: I dont have the libraries `ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource`, `ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get` & `use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection` at my disposal. Moreover, `ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource` conflicts with `ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource`

Comment: Please check this Link: (Decorating the API Platform Documentation Normalizer) https://timobakx.dev/php/api-platform/2021/06/06/altering-api-documentation-generated-by-apip.html Just do it step by step :-) It works for the older versions.